# Print function on replit isn't working. I don't think it's the syntax: i've tried it on a different editor and the code worked flawlessly. any ideas?

Tags: python

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOkR7.png)

Print function not working in replit.

I'm not sure if its a glitch with replit, but my print function isn't working. I tried it with just print("Hello world") and it still didn't work.
I tried this same code on a different code editor, and it worked. print(len(input("What is your name?")))

Comment: _I'm not sure if its a glitch with replit_ ... so you didn't notice the actual error that it gave you??

Comment: It stated that the issue was on line 6, but I saw no issue with the line. With the help of another user,  I learned that the issue was actually with line 3 and not line 6.

Answer (score 0):

One of your parentheses on line 3 isn't closed properly.

Comment: Thanks Squarish. I thought the problem was solely line 6 and nothing else. I'll keep my eyes open next time!